# Is my base case wrong? - Recurrence relation for algorithm with multiple recurrences

Tags: algorithm, relation, recurrence

I need to create a recurrence relation to capture the number of comparisons performed in this algorithm:

```
Func(n)
    if n = 1
        print "!"
        return 1
    else
        return Func(n-1) * Func(n-1) * Func(n-1)
```

This is what I came up with - but I can't seem to figure out what I did wrong...

Base Case: M(1) = 0

```
M(n) = 3[M(n-1)] 
 = 3[3[M(n-2)]]
 = 3[3[3[M(n-3)]]]
 = 3^i[M(n-i)]

i = n-1 //to get base case

M(n) = 3^(n-1)[M(n-(n-1))] 
 = 3^(n-1)[M(1)] 
 = 3^(n-1)[0] 
 = 0 //????????????
```

Is my base case wrong? If so, why? Please and thank you for your help.

Comment: What led you to think that M(1) = 0?

Comment: @wookie919 Honestly, I have no idea. I always get confused with base cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Base case (n equals 1), M(1) should be taken as 1 (time complexity constant),

```
M(n) = 3^(n-1) then
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is about the number of comparisons.

Every time you call the function, you execute exactly one comparison.

When the outcome is `n=1`, you are done, and when the outcome is `n>1`, you perform three recursive calls with `n-1`.

Clearly,

```
M(1) = 1 
M(n) = 3 M(n-1)
```

By computing `M` for increasing values of `n`, you easily spot the pattern: `1, 3, 9, 27, 81...`

Comment: There is a funny thing about this function when you look at what it computes: F(n) = F(n-1)^3 = F(n-2)^9 = F(n-3)^27 = ... F(n-k)^(3^k) = ... F(1)^(3^(n-1)) = 1. It always returns 1, after a possibly veeeeery long time.